# how to manipulate data after retrieving from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am fetching a url which is stored in mysql database to a php variable.

> $data_want_to_manipulate=$row['data'];

suppose the `$data_want_to_manipulate` is  `viewarticle.php?id=121`.
from that i want to take out only 121 means what I can do?.

Comment: you can use explode...

Comment: how can i use that?. @Vicky

Comment: From where you are getting `id=121`?

Comment: I _think_ this is just a string / text processing Q and you should remove the mysql tag.  Sounds like you question is how to convert viewarticle.php?id=XXX to XXX in php.  Readup on string manipulation (ie substrings, string spiltting) and regex in php and the solution should present itself.

Comment: @b0s3 is this question is clear?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
<?php $data_want_to_manipulate1=explode('=',$data_want_to_manipulate);
    echo $data_want_to_manipulate1[1];?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `explode` function like this

```
$str=explode('=',$data_want_to_manipulate);
echo $str[1]             // 121
or 
echo end($str);           //121
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: why it is not providing the answer ?? what is the issue??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php 
$data_want_to_manipulate='viewarticle.php?id=121';
$str=explode('=',$data_want_to_manipulate);
echo $str[1]  ;           // 121
?>
```